# PowerBI PowerShell Cmtlets Enumerate Workspace Reports in CSV

Tags: powershell, shell, csv, scripting, powerbi

I'm running the following PowerShell Script to find all of my available Workspaces in Power BI and also the Users, Reports, and Datasets in those Workspaces.

This works fine and shows me the data I'm looking for inside the Powershell window:

```
#Get Power BI Workspaces
$ws = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All -Include All 
$ws
```

However I'm running into issues when I export to CSV:

```
$ws | Export-Csv C:\Users\flyn50500771\pbi_report_dump\workspaces.csv
$ws | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\Users\flyn50500771\pbi_report_dump\workspaces.json"
```

When I'm exporting to CSV, in the "Reports" column, I'm getting the values:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models.Report,Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.Report]
```

My goal is to run a script to return all existing Workspaces, then be able to "drilldown" into that workspace to see the reports within, then the users, then the associated datasets.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are even exporting the type to the csv file, then you need to use the -NoTypeInformation parameter:

```
$ws | Export-Csv "filepath" -NoTypeInformation
```